# Getting AngularJS multilink error after upgrade from v. 1.4

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-compile

I have a big directive with sub-directives where I'm getting the error. Exactly, it happens on the step when calling `transcludeFn()` in the `link` function of main directive:

```
var link = function ($scope, elem, attr, parentCtrl, transcludeFn) {
            // Run all nested directives in order to properly register columns in grid.
            transcludeFn();

            // Add compiled content to directive element.
            elem.after($compile(template)($scope));
        };
```

Can't figure out with that issue. What I've missed in the docs? Adding stuff with `$onInit` as [described here](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/migration#-compile-) doesn't help (*I'm not sure I was doing that correctly*).

I'm not familiar with AngularJS so any help will be a good point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I really don't know what is the root of the issue but I've solved it by passing a dummy function into `transcludeFn()`:

```
var link = function ($scope, elem, attr, parentCtrl, transcludeFn) {
    // Run all nested directives in order to properly register columns in grid.
    transcludeFn();
    transcludeFn(function() {
        // do nothing, only for fixing upgrade issue 
    });

    // Add compiled content to directive element.
    elem.after($compile(template)($scope));
};
```

Comment: +1 Your solution fixed this error while upgrading AngularJS 1.5 to 1.6: "Error: [$compile:multilink] This element has already been linked."